# How to get a file updated server side at given times

Tags: php, xml, download

I'm not sure where to start with this one, so any help pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.

What I have is a php script saving an XML file from an ftp site to the server (on demand) for parsing/displaying. I've been working with fairly small XML files so this has worked quite well.

Now I have a new vendor whose XML files are over 5MB, so fetching them on demand isn't really an option.

What I want to know is if there is a way to get the server to fetch the file at certain times (twice a day), regardless if the site has been hit to use the data.

Like I said, kind of in the dark on this, so any advice/suggestions/direction is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
-Ted

Comment: The standard tool for scheduled tasks like this is [cron](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=cron)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Linux hosting you could use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to schedule the fetching script execution. Other solution is to call the script url remotely two times a day by some other machine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bat/shell file containing : `php YOUR_DOWNLOADER_PARSER.php`
Add PHP bin directory to your `%PATH%` or `$PATH` environment variable
Create a Cron Job or Scheduled Task to run N Times/Day at your fixed time

Hope that helps :)

Comment: " bat/shell file " why ?